# Recursively execute latexmk -c on folders

Tags: recursion, find, latexmk

I'd like to execute the command `latexmk -c` on all of the directories inside a directory, e.g.,

`.`

`./test-dir`

The effect is to remove all of the auxiliary files created curing latex compilation.

I've tried using the `find` command to tell me about the directories and then execute a command, like so:

`find -type d -exec latexmk -c \;`

But unfortunately, that command only has the effect of removing the auxiliary files in the directory in which I call it, not in the subdirectory (`test-dir` in this example).

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem: I wanted to convert .tex files recursively. The final solution for me was:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -execdir latexmk -pdf {} \;
```

The secret here is to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` which executes the command in the directory the file was found. So the solution to your problem is most likely:

```
find -type d -execdir latexmk -c \;
```